# Errors while porting code to silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a C# class library project in my solution, in which I added a User Control and pasted the following code from my WPF application.

The xaml looks all fine, but I am getting certain errors on compiling. For eg:

```
1) System.Windows.DataFormats' does not contain a definition for 'StringFormat'
2) System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' does not contain a definition for 'Background' and no extension method 'Background' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' could be found
3) System.Windows.Media.Colors' does not contain a definition for 'LightCoral'
4) System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' does not contain a definition for 'Background' and no extension method 'Background' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I am not sure why these errors are occuring and these are related to TextBox's background, Drag Drop, DataFormats etc. The **.xaml.cs** code is here as well. http://pastebin.com/CY8E8prz

Comment: I imagine its because WPF and Silverlight are different frameworks.

Comment: You need to do more than just paste the code. The namespaces are different for a start.

Comment: @jrummell: Doesn't look like much of a difference in this context here. The full .xaml.cs doe is there in the above link which';; make thingsmore clear.

Comment: @ChrisF: By pasting, I didn't mean pasting all of it without seeing anything : -) . I am not sure if there's a difference of the namespace for what I have wrtitten above in the link

Comment: As I understand it, Silverlight has its own subset of the .NET framework. WPF on the other hand, has the full .NET framework available to it.

Comment: @jrummell: So, there's no `DragDrop`, `e.LeftButton`, `MouseButtonState` and `StringFormat` in silverlight? None of this? –

Comment: @user1240679 We don't have every type memorized.  When you ask these questions, we check the MSDN.  It is a very useful tool.  I suggest you familiarize yourself with it if you have not already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the properties referred to by the errors, because Silverlight simply doesn't have them or they have a different name (WPF and Silverlight aren't exactly the same, the former has *more* features than the latter).

A few examples:

- To color the background of a `TextBlock`, you can wrap it in a `Border` (adjusting positioning/sizing attributes accordingly).
- `LightCoral` looks like a color name, you'll have to look up something similar or use `Color.FromArgb()`

In short, copy-pasted code from WPF to Silverlight very rarely works as-is.

Comment: So, there's no `DragDrop`, `e.LeftButton`, `MouseButtonState` and `StringFormat`. None of this?

Comment: Many things are different from WPF to Silverlight, unfortunately. You'll need to check your code and fix it one error at a time, unless some kind of "converter" exists (I'm not aware of any, sorry). MSDN and Google will be your best friends during the process.

Answer (score 1):

Textblock has no background in Silverlight, only WPF. I'm sure the rest of your errors follow suit. For that particular issue, place the textblock over another control or use a label instead. For the color, just look up the RGB and set it directly. I'm not sure on the other errors exactly.